# Record entry error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, transactions

This is my table:

```
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "book_name"
    t.integer  "cart_unit"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "pages"
    t.integer  "stock"
    t.text     "synopsis"
    t.integer  "mrp"
    t.string   "author"
    t.string   "publisher"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.string   "genre_name"
    t.integer  "book_id"
    t.integer  "genre_id"
    t.integer  "discount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

This is my model for the same:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = 'book_id'
    belongs_to:Product
end
```

This is what is happening in the rails console:

```
irb(main):044:0> book = Book.new(book_name:"The Girl on the Train", cart_unit:0, product_id:0001, pages:395, stock:50, synopsis:"Commuter Rachel Watson catches daily glimpses of a seemingly perfect couple, Scott and Megan, from the window of her train. One day, Watson witnesses something shocking unfold in the backyard of the strangers' home. Rachel tells the authorities what she thinks she saw after learning that Megan is now missing and feared dead. Unable to trust her own memory, the troubled woman begins her own investigation, while police suspect that Rachel may have crossed a dangerous line.", mrp:500, author:"Paula Hawkins", publisher:"Riverhead Books",rating:8, genre_name:"Thriller", genre_id:1, book_id:1001, discount:0)
=> #<Book id: 1001, book_name: "The Girl on the Train", cart_unit: 0, product_id: 1, pages: 395, stock: 50, synopsis: "Commuter Rachel Watson catches daily glimpses of a...", mrp: 500, author: "Paula Hawkins", publisher: "Riverhead Books", rating: 8, genre_name: "Thriller", book_id: 1001, genre_id: 1, discount: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):045:0> book.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

Why is this happening? I don't understand why the transaction is rolling back.
EDIT: On running 'book.save!'

```
book.save!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Product must exist
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `block in save!'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in `save!'
    from (irb):53
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This is the product table:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.string   "product_name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

This is the model for the product table

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = 'product_id'
end
```

Comment: Are there any validations in place?

Comment: Use `book.valid?` to check for errors.

Comment: @Gerry book.valid?
=> false

Comment: try `book.save!`, and paste the errors

Comment: @seaify-Freelancer that's what I've written in the question

Comment: no, you are write `book.save`, not `book.save!`, huge difference. when the record is invalid, the `save!` will throw the exception. take care

Comment: Now `book.errors' to see the errors.

Comment: @Gerry 


`book.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x005639f508b670 @base=#<Book id: 1001, book_name: "The Girl on the Train", cart_unit: 0, product_id: 1, pages: 395, stock: 50, synopsis: "Commuter Rachel Watson catches daily glimpses of a...", mrp: 500, author: "Paula Hawkins", publisher: "Riverhead Books", rating: 8, genre_name: "Thriller", book_id: 1001, genre_id: 1, discount: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:Product=>["must exist"]}, @details={:Product=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>`

Comment: your products table is empty ? If so, try to create one. and re-try your save.

Comment: @孙悟空 yeah. Lmao I think that just might be it

Comment: @孙悟空 it's still not working though.

Comment: In Product Model, Just remove `self.primary_key = 'product_id'` and re-try it. I think the problem is that foreign_key and primary_key have same name (product_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.

```
book.errors
```

It will provide you details.
Alternatively, you can first do this

```
book = Book.new(params)
```

And then this

```
book.save!
```

It will raise runtime error and show you errors.

After looking at your last comment, your product doesn't exist. First create Product of which id you are passing in Book record.

Comment: I made the Product but it still says Product does not exist. Is there a special notation on how I should be writing the product_id?

Comment: It should work until you add this validation in your book model
`validates :product, presence: true`
Few suggestions are that you should rename your columng `product_id` and `book_id` to something like `product_code` and `book_code`.
Because by default rails create foreign key using Table's unique Id.
After renaming your column names, you should explicitely provide foreign key in book model like this `belongs_to :product, foreign_key: 'product_code'` . it should work.

Comment: Do not forget to exit rails console after doing such changes.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Rails 5, where `belongs_to` is required by default. If you want product_id to be optional,

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = 'book_id'
    belongs_to: Product, optional: true
end
```

Comment: it still says that the product must exist